# Git branch rename (non-master) - Atlassian Stash

Tags: git

I renamed a local branch (non-master) and then wanted to rename the remote barnch (Atlassian stash hosted repository).

But, no matter what I do the branch rename is not reflected on remote.

This is what I did

```
git branch SR1234
git checkout SR1234
git push --set-upstream origin SR1234
git add --all
git commit -m "...."
git push
```

Then renamed the 'current' branch

```
git branch -m SR5678
```

Then tried to rename the branch on remote

```
git push origin :SR1234
$ git push origin :SR1234
To ssh://<repo>.git
 - [deleted]         SR1234


$ git push --set-upstream origin SR5678
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://<repo>.git
 * [new branch]      SR5678 -> Sr1234
Branch SR5678 set up to track remote branch SR1234 from origin.
```

The trouble is that on remote (hosted on atlassian stash), I see the old branch name no matter what I do. Only local, I see the new branch name.

How can I change the remote branch name?

Comment: Use the explicit push syntax, included a full refspec: `git push -u origin SR5678:SR5678`

Answer (score 18):

The complete way to rename a branch locally and remotely is something like:

```
# rename it locally
git branch -m old-name new-name

# push the new one remotely
git push --set-upstream origin new-name

# delete the old one remotely
git push origin :old-name
```

**BUT ...**

Doing so, if more than one person is working on the repo, you must inform all workers about your changes. If not, they could recreate your old branch by pushing their local history (which still contains its reference):

```
# hardly refresh a local clone if possible
git fetch --prune --all
```

If the local update can not be done (the local branch does not have the same name as your original one for instance), git will inform users on checkout with a message like:

> Your branch is based on '...', but the upstream is gone.

But it will still push the old history on next `git push` if the user does not process the rename locally (and manually).

So **you should remotely rename branches ONLY if it is really required to avoid problems** or if you just pushed the original one (assuming no one pulled from that time).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem occurs due to your `.git/config` file's `branch.SR5678.merge` variable.

Steps you followed for renaming a branch

```
1) git branch -m SR5678
2) git push origin :SR1234
3) git push --set-upstream origin SR5678
```

So after 1 & 2 commands, your local branch name has been changed but the `merge` variable still refers to the older branch name. like below:

```
[branch "SR5678"]
     remote = origin
     merge = refs/heads/SR1234
```

And this branch name is used for `Push` to or `Pull` from commands. Hence, your 3rd command will still push into old named branch for a remote location.

Any of below can be used for solutions:

```
[1]
git branch -m SR1234 SR5678
git push origin :SR1234 
git push -u origin SR5678:SR5678

[2]
git branch -m SR1234 SR5678
git push origin :SR1234 
git push --set-upstream origin SR5678:SR5678

[3]
git branch -m SR1234 SR5678
git push origin :SR1234 
git config branch.SR5678.merge refs/heads/SR5678
git push -u origin SR5678
```

Answer (score 0):

When you moved your branch, it still knows about the tracking branch `Sr1234`. When you push a nothing to a branch by `:BRANCH` you delete that branch on the remote.

To create a branch on the remote you can tell into what branch you want to push

```
git push --set-upstream origin SR5687:SR5687
```

As its part of your move that the old branch got removed, it was possibly a good idea to remove the old name in the remote repository, as you don't seem to need anymore.